# BroadcastReceiver null pointer when navigation away from application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm detecting internet connection via a BroadcastReceiver (below). I have a TextView which toggles visible/invisible to show if there is an internet connection. Because the BroadcastReceiver is static, the TextView must be static. However, if I navigate away from the app (minimize it) and toggle the internet connection on/off, I receive a null pointer on `internetConnect.setVisibility` occasionally. What's a way around this problem?

```
static TextView internetConnect;

in onCreate ---> internetConnect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.internet);

public static class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity.NetworkStateReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Network connectivity change");
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final NetworkInfo ni = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (ni != null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                internetConnect.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE)) {
                internetConnect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            internetConnect.bringToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new NetworkStateReceiver();

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(receiver != null) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
     if (receiver != null) {
         this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
     }
}
```

Comment: by minimize you mean to exit application? or pressing home button to put it on back??

Comment: yes, exit. it crashes while I'm on another app or just on the phone home screen.

Comment: @Saqib it makes no difference, when the activity is not visible you will always get a NullPointerException if you try and access it's views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call unregisterReceiver for your broadcast receiver when your app is in the background. You can do this in onPause or onStop.

Comment: Ah yes. Unregister it on onStop/onPause and register it again on onResume.

Comment: Yep, exactly. I generally use onResume and onPause, but some cases require you to use onStart and onStop instead.

Comment: Nope. still randomly crashing when I'm away from the app

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?